# Windows PowerShell ISE Module:Action shows up, but says isn't recognized when ran

Tags: powershell

So, i have this powershell module i designed, that's meant to run in the Windows PowerShell ISE console.

The main.psm1 file:

```
function FindAndReplaceLine {
    $currentLine = $psISE.CurrentFile.Editor.CurrentLine
    $scriptText = $psISE.CurrentFile.Editor.GetText()
    $lines = $scriptText -split "`r?`n"

    if ($currentLine -ge 0 -and $currentLine -lt $lines.Count) {
        $currentText = $lines[$currentLine]

        # Replace the line with the new text
        $lines[$currentLine] = 'Replacement line'

        # Join the modified lines back into a single text
        $newText = $lines -join "`r`n"

        # Set the new text in the editor
        $psISE.CurrentFile.Editor.SetText($newText)
    }
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function FindAndReplaceLine
```

the addon.psd1 file:

```
    @{
    ModuleVersion = '1.1'
    GUID = '1c1507d8-191b-4090-9ced-d1fb551c8ea8'
    #use new-guid to generate GUID in pwsh
    Author = '****'
    Description = 'My Enhanced PowerShell ISE Addon'
    PowerShellVersion = '5.1'
    FunctionsToExport = 'FindAndReplaceLine'
}
```

commands i ran to import the module:

```
import-module C:/Users/****/Downloads/psp_addon/main.psm1
import-module C:/Users/****/Downloads/psp_addon/addon.psd1
```

what i added to the `C:\Users\****\dist\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1` file:

```
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add("Find and Replace Line", { FindAndReplaceLine }, "Ctrl+Shift+F")
```

output from the ISE console when I open it:

```
Action               DisplayName           Shortcut                        Submenus
------               -----------           --------                        --------
 FindAndReplaceLine  Find and Replace Line System.Windows.Input.KeyGesture {}
```

output when i click the submenu or run the command:

```
FindAndReplaceLine : The term 'FindAndReplaceLine' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2
+  FindAndReplaceLine
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (FindAndReplaceLine:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Windows version:Windows 11 Pro 22H2 build 22621.1702
powershell version(preinstalled):10.0.22621.1635
PowerShell 7 preview version 7.4.0.3